# How to modify post content?

Tags: posts, database, hooks

I still haven't figured this out yet. 
Is this the right way? I tried `$_POST['content'] = "nothing"` and `$_POST['content'] = 0` neither work for me. I'm using following way

```
function changeContent() {
     $_POST['content'] = "nothing"; 
}
add_action('publish_post', 'changeContent');
```

I want to change the content before it's written into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check out the `content_edit_pre` filter.

Your example would then look like this:

```
function wpse89725_pre_edit_content( $content, $post_id ) {
   $content = "nothing";
   return $content;
}
add_filter( 'content_edit_pre', 'wpse89725_pre_edit_content', 10, 2 );
```

You can read more about this filter in the Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_edit_pre

**Edit:**

You can also try the `edit_post_content` filter:

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_content', 'my_pre_edit_content', 10, 2 );
```

Since we have in the file `/wp-includes/post.php` these lines:

```
 $value = apply_filters("edit_{$field}", $value, $post_id);
 // Old school
 $value = apply_filters("{$field_no_prefix}_edit_pre", $value, $post_id);
```

both of these filters should work, but the filters `*_edit_pre` seems to be on the way out and replaced by `edit_*`.

Comment: thanks!  but here it says content_edit_pre is depreciated in version 3.5? I tried a few related ones, but they are all said to be depreciated? so strange.. http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/content_edit_pre

Comment: It's a dynamic hook:  `$value = apply_filters("{$field_no_prefix}_edit_pre", $value, $post_id);` so that might be the reason why the adambrown-scraper can't find it. It works on my 3.5.1 install.

Comment: I updated the answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot~ I tried both and both work, and I'll use the latter. I chose your answer already, btw do you have any idea why intercepting post value won't work?   $_POST['content'] = "nothing"

Comment: great thanks - I think the post has already been saved when you call the `publish_post` action. Your example might work with the `init` hook and the `$_POST['post_content']` but I don't think it's ideal to mess with the `$_POST` variable ;-)